# Change the domain metric in order for a function to be uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

This was an exam question we had a month ago, which I have been thinking since then, but I can not come up with a solution.

Given metric spaces $(X,d), (X,p)$, and a continuous function $f: (X,d) \to (X,p)$.

a) Can we change the metric $d$ in order to make $f$ uniformly continuous, without changing the open sets of $(X,d)$?

b) Can we change the metric $d$ in order to make $f$ Lipschitz, without changing the open sets of $(X,d)$?

My thoughts:

- For (a): The only way I could think of in order to keep the same open sets in $(X,d)$, is to scale the metric by a factor, which does not help, since considering for example the function $f(x) = 1/x$, we would still have the function not uniformly continuous.
- For (a): Changing the metric to discrete metric is not a solution, since all subsets will be open, and hence we are changing the open sets of $(X,d)$.
- I also thought of keeping the metric $p$ for both metric spaces, but it is not a solution, since closed sets can be mapped to open sets.
- For (b): If it could be solved, it implies (a), but intuitively I believe there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D(x,y)=d(x,y)+p(f(x),f(y))$. Check that $D(x_n,x) \to 0$ iff $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ [Continuity of $f$ is used here]. This implies that $(X,d)$ and $(X,D)$ have the same closed sets, hence also same open sets. Now $p(f(x),f(y)) \leq D(x,y)$ so $f$ becomes (uniformly continuous as well as) Lipschitz on $(X,D)$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Reading it is very intuitive, clear and makes complete sense. I am very disappointed that it didn't cross my mind.